# Switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX - fontspec and unicode-math defaults

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm currently switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX and I personally like to write down the defaults in my default preamble to be able to modify some slight things (but not accidentally changing everything).

So far I didn't found the default fonts for `fontspec` and `unicode-math` (somehow quite the only packages to add when using XeLaTex besides `xltxtra` right? Sorry for the side question but it can be really confusing to get what has to be changed when doing the switch). Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: The default text font is Latin Modern.

Comment: xltxtra is not recommended now. Just use fontspec directly.

Comment: Oh then that't one of these things one often reads in older docs I guess. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fontspec` sets hundreds of things and `unicode-math` thousands, but I assume you mean the main user-settable fonts that you might want to change.

`fontspec` defaults to Latin Modern so more or less the same as

```
    \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
```

which is the same font as used if the package is not loaded (the family name is `lmr` with the default settings but it is the same font)

`fc-list` gives the following locations in texlive 2020

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf: Latin Modern Roman,LM Roman 10:style=10 Regular,Regular
```

and

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf: Latin Modern Math:style=Regular
```

`unicode-math` defaults to latin modern math so

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
```

which is not the same as not using the package, the default math font in xelatex is the 7 bit Computer Modern and the classic tfm math layout not the OpenType math layout.

Depending on your font-config settings you may want to use the filename rather than the internal fontname so

`lmroman10-regular.otf` and `latinmodern-math.otf`  in the above commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
 \setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}

% \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the sans-serif etc fonts are the "derivations" of the lmodern font? And is there anything else to do when switching to xelatex?

Comment: @atticus most basic "as described in the latex book" documents "just work", many packages (hyperref,graphicx,tikz, etc) detect the engine and do the right thing automatically so you do not need to change anything, but if your document was full of pdftex specific extensions such as `\pdfliteral` or `\pdfinfo` etc then those primitives will not work (but normally you should never use those primitives directly anyway) so it all depends....

Comment: @atticus luatex is much closer to pdftex (and in fact was derived from it) if you are looking for a unicode tex that is "close" to pdftex.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but somhow I cannot find the `Latin Modern Regular` font (`fc-list` doesn't contain it and a manual search didn't lead to a result) and neither can `fontspec`. Are you sure this is the default? (`latin modern math` is contained in some `mathjax` directory)

Comment: @atticus well that's weird sorry!! I even had a test file but I managed to copy the line incorrectly.. Roman not Regular.

Comment: @atticus I extended the answer to give filename as well as fontname versions.

Comment: With that it works now (but somehow its weird `latinmodern-math.otf` works, but with `Latin Modern Math` unicode-math says that the font does not contain Script `"Math"`)

Comment: @atticus that probably means fontconfig has found the wrong (older?) font, what  path does `fc-list 'Latin Modern Math`  report?

Comment: Many (24) Paths like this `/usr/share/fonts/mathjax2/HTML-CSS/Latin-Modern/woff/LatinModernMathJax_Shapes-Regular.woff`

Comment: @atticus you don't want woff fonts with xetex

Comment: Then is seams that the search path is not quite right for xelatex

Comment: if you give a filename then normal tex file searching is used. If you use a font name then font config is used and you may not have configured fontconfig to search the texlive tree (it comes with a fontconfig file but it isn't activated by default)

Comment: Ah right that's in the docs, makes sense. Thanks for your detailed support ;)