# unicode-math default math fonts

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I just tried to use the default math font as given by `unicode-math`, but somehow the symbols for `\sum`, `\prod` and (some) greek letters are missing when using `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}` (as is suggested by the `unicode-math` package). Without explicitly setting the font it works perfectly well.

The trouble is just that I need to set fonts for some explicit characters (to be able to display them) but the remaining characters should not change (since the defaults just work well).

PS: This is some kind of a followup from [Switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX - fontspec and unicode-math defaults](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573137/switching-from-latex-to-xelatex-fontspec-and-unicode-math-defaults)

What fonts are used in addition to `latinmodern-math.otf` in the default settings of `unicode-math`?

EDIT: M(not)WE

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% ----- Packages -----
% XeTeX
\usepackage{unicode-math-xetex}
\usepackage{fontspec-xetex}[Ligatures=TeX]
\usepackage{xunicode} % for the inputfile encoding and unicode macros

% ----- Settings -----
\KOMAoptions{
        paper=a4,           % set papersize
        fontsize=12pt,      % set fontsize to 12pt
        parskip=half,       % half a line will seperate paragraphs
}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="27D5]
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="27D6]
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="27D7]
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="2A1D]
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="2A1E] % bigtriangleleft -> antijoin
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="22C9] % ltimes -> leftsemijoin
% \setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="22CA] % rtimes -> rightsemijoin

\begin{document}
\[
        \prod_{k=1}^{n} c \cdot a_k = c^n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^na_k % this is not right ;)
\]

$\alpha \leftouterjoin \beta$

\end{document}
```

Produces this:
[image: result]

Comment: that is the default. As always if you want someone to debug some code it helps if you show the complete test document and the log file that you get.

Comment: \sum and \prod works fine. Something must be wrong in your document or your installation. Show a small but complete example along with the log-file.

Comment: in comments on your oder question you clarified unicode-math was failing as your local font paths were incorrect and you were picking up Many (24) Paths like this /usr/share/fonts/mathjax2/HTML-CSS/Latin-Modern/woff/LatinModernMathJax_Shapes-Regular.woff  is that still the case?

Comment: Sorry my bad, the mwe is now there. And no I didn't fixed the font paths yet, but I'm working with the `.otf` Font-Names so as far as I know this should not be a problem.

Comment: unrelated but don't load xunicode, and use fontspec, not fontspec-xetex.

Comment: `\usepackage{unicode-math-xetex}
\usepackage{fontspec-xetex}[Ligatures=TeX]
\usepackage{xunicode} % for the inputfile encoding and unicode macros`  is not the correct way to load either package, don't use xunicode (unless you know you need it for compatibility with something) and j specify `fontspec` and unicode-math`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer quicker but shorter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and I didn't see the unicode-math-xetex ;-(.

Comment: your question asks about `\sum` and `\prod` but your example document does not use them at all. What is your question?

Comment: Oh the example is just about greek letters, but I'll add sum and prod as well. Somehow greek letters (EDIT: and `prod` and `sum`) work after using `unicode-math` instead of `unicode-math-xetex` (thought it would be better to specify what engine is used...)

Comment: I don't think the `...-xetex` package files are documented at all are they? They are just an internal organisation to keep apart some internal code paths that need to be separate for xetex and luatex.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks to both of you

Comment: I suggest `NewCMMath-Regular.otf` instead of STIX for the missing outer join symbols.

Comment: Any special reason?

Comment: the join symbol from stix does not match cm at all, it is far too heavy (stix is designed to match Times Roman) if the new CM math font has that symbol it would definitely be a better choice (or use it for all of the math rather than latin modern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remove the spurious or commented out lines from your example, it works without error

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

% ----- Packages -----
% XeTeX
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[range="27D5]


\begin{document}

\[
        \prod_{k=1}^{n} c \cdot a_k = c^n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^na_k % this is not right ;)
\]
$\alpha \leftouterjoin \beta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Taking the Greek from latin modern and the outer join from stix2.